# Creating a LinearLayout and ListView programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

So im following this code, the popular lazy loading example: [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)

I set up in my own project something similar with a layout xml along with the following code:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">


      <!--  Screen Design for VIDEOS -->
      <ListView
      android:id="@+id/list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

It works great, however if I add a ListView programmatically like so:

```
 this.list = new ListView(this);
        this.list.setClickable(true);

        addContentView(this.list, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

The listview displays with the default icons, but no images are loaded. So the xml layout works, but programmatically it doesnt.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Looks like when I use an xml layout it only shows the images that I have loaded in the LazyLoader example project. I have the project imported in the same workspace. They must be affecting each other.

Essentially, I cannot load any other image other than the ones in the example, which makes me believe it has something to do with the cache?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I didn't add external cache permissions to the manifest.